# How does first-time-plugged router instruct OS to open a webpage for it's GUI?

Tags: windows, networking, router

After I brought home a new ASUS router, I turned it on, plugged it to my PC and a couple seconds later I noticed that a browser window opened for router's local web-interface: `router.asus.com` (192.168.1.1)

Later I hard reset the router and scanned the whole turning on process with wireshark - yet all I saw were mostly "informational" packets like DHCP, DNS, etc.
I didn't see any "instructional" packets like "open router.asus.com for me", - the first occurence of "asus" string was in a DNS packet coming from my PC!

How does this webpage-opening event occur?
 Bonus: Is it windows-specific maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is (practically) windows specific.  The router and windows are using [uPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) to autodetect and configure.